# Is this a function?

Tags: functions

Is the set $\theta=\{\big((x,y),(3y,2x,x+y)\big):x,y ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$ a function? If so, what is its domain, codomain, and range?

This is probably a dumb question. I understand what a function is, but the three elements in the ordered pair got me confused.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Book of Proof by Richard Hammack. Chapter 12.1, question #12.

Comment: Yes, it is a function. Domain is $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and co-domain is $V\times W$ where $V$ is a vector space over $R$ of dimension $2$ and $W$ is a vector space over $R$ of dimension 3.

Comment: In this case, the notation $(3y,2x,x+y)$ refers to an ordered triple of numbers.  As Jayesh Badwaik, I would consider it an element of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, I would call this the *graph* of a function.

Comment: @Andrew: The usual set-theoretic formalization of "function" identifies a function with its graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, presumably one from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, although the domain and codomain could potentially be smaller. You have an ordered pair in which the first element is itself an ordered pair (of real numbers), and the second is an ordered triple (of real numbers).

I'm used to codomain and range meaning the same thing. If you meant image for one of them, I can't think of a better description than $\{(3y,2x,x+y):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Comment: @Mathh Pressland: I do not believe the co-domain is  $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, rather I believe the co-domain is a vector space $W$ where an element of $W$ is $w$ of the form $(u,v)$ where $u \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. This space might be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ though.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik: No -- the elements of the _set that represents the function_ are of the form $(u,v)$ meaning that $f(u)=v$. Each _value_ of the function is a $v$ that lives in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: The codomain is not the same as the range.  A function always has a domain and a codomain, but the codomain can contain more points than the range of the function.  It is impossible to actually say what the codomain of a function is just by looking at it's "graph" set - you can only with certainly say what the range is, and that the codomain must contain the range.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Okay, thanks. I was not aware of this notation. So you are saying the notation is equivalent to the below?
\begin{equation}
\theta(x,y) = (3y,2x,x+y)
\end{equation}

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's what I was thinking of - the terminology I'm used to is that "range" as you've used it is called the image, and range and codomain are synonyms, but I was vaguely aware that this isn't used by everybody.

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

A general definition of function follows that of relation, a subset of the cartesian product of two sets $A\times B$, with the further prescription that each element of $A$ is in relation with exactly one element of $B$.

In such view, your set $\theta$ seems a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^3$.

The domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the range or image is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. When $\mathbb{R}^3$ is viewed as a linear space and given the explicit linear and homogeneous form of the given formulas, this subset is a subspace.